# Filter on Arabic strings

Tags: sql-server, unicode

We are migrating data from one `Sql-server` database to another. There is one column of type `nvarchar` that may contain Arabic characters. I needed to separate English names from the Arabic ones and put each in its own column. Something like:

```
insert NewTable(EnglishDescription)
select Description from OldTable where Description does not contain 'Arabic characters'

insert NewTable(ArabicDescription)
select Description from OldTable where Description contains 'Arabic characters'
```

I have seen similar scenarios here in SO but none of them shows how to achieve that in `sql-server`

Comment: Why do you have to separate arabic from other entries? Are you really sure that's what you actually want?

Comment: @Deduplicator The new application has both languages. Each user can see his own description based on his language. Yes I'm pretty sure of that.

Comment: That's a quite imperfect solution. While you can test whether any character in a string is in the arabic script (though I don't know exactly how), that does not actually mean the person wants the arabic description. Or understands them. Does hold vice-versa as well.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't understand why its an imperfect solution. Not all Arab users understand English so they choose the Arabic interface with Arabic entries. Besides, In UAE, bills must contain product names with both languages (by law).

Comment: What other characters do you expect to exist than Unicode characters? Do you think “A” is not a Unicode character? If you mean distinguishing between characters of the Latin script from characters of the Arabic script, you need to formulate your question (and its title) in terms of that. And it is quite possible that your *real* problem is still something completely different.

Comment: As @JukkaK.Korpela stated, you might want to change the title as both scripts are `unicode` characters using `nvarchar`. Check my answer for what  exactly you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get strings that contain Arabic characters, then here is how you do it:

```
insert NewTable(ArabicDescription)
select Description from OldTable where Description like N'%[أ-ي]%'
```

You can get those for Latin by adding `not` right before`like`.

However, when querying for Arabic character that would bring up strings that might contain both Latin & Arabic.